# How can I apply a function to elements inside my list?

Tags: python, list

How can I multiply everything in my list by a number or how can I just apply a random function to my elements?
I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: `map(your_function, yourList)`

Comment: If you added some code and what you are trying to do  it might help.

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=map#map), a book, or go through one of the many online Python tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

list comprehension:
`y = [x*2 for x in l]`
lambda function:
`y = map(lambda for x: x * 5, in l)`
looping each element of the list:
`for x in l:`

Answer (score 0):

There are hundreds of ways to achieve this. To get each element of the list you can use the following:

```
for element in list:
    print element
    function(element)
    print element * 4
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, i meant through decimals, my question was not clear enough. I'm running a function F through all the elements in my list but it is only going through the whole numbers in the list but i want it to run through decimals as well.
x = f(y) for y in x:
and my list is x = [0,2] but i need it to run through the decimal values as well.